# Access localhost xampp on a different PC connected using wifi

Tags: php, networking, xampp

I want my htdocs folder on my xampp to be accessible by other PCs. I searched for an answer and it says that you should just edit your htaccess file.

I am unsure of where my htaccess file is but I found one on htdocs\forbidden folder.

So my htaccess file looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/forbidden/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from 192.168.254.254
allow from 192.168.254.101
```

The two IPs are the 2 pcs i want to connect.

What should the two PCs enter in their browser to access my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should enter your IP address (in local network, smth like 192.168.254.1)

Comment: I tested it and it shows: "new xampp security concept.. etc."

Comment: i think now you should edit your httpd-xampp.conf file and put two PCs IP addresses in "Allow from" line of some "LocationMatch" block

Comment: It worked already but thanks anyway! I forgot to add the name of my folder after the IP.